# archetype-catalog of jcenter.bintray.com to old when proxing it with Sonatype Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, bintray

I have problems to reach some artefacts from jcenter/bintray over Sonatype Nexus.

I created a maven2 Nexus configuration which points to http://jcenter.bintray.com (remote storage location). I set "Download Remote Index" to true.

Nevertheless /nexus/content/repositories/com.bintray.jcenter/archetype-catalog.xml did not contain my desired artefact. The catalog itself is not empty.

Browsing jcenter.bintray.com/com/moowork/gradle/gradle-grunt-plugin/0.4/ reveals the artefact.

Any idea, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a proxy in Nexus with the following url works for me:
http://dl.bintray.com/srs/maven/.

At that url there are no maven catalog files, but you can navigate through the artifact structure. Nexus works on repos without catalog, too.

It looks like you have to point Nexus to the project specific repository, and not to the root url.